# Bash script starts my program two times

Tags: bash

I have a custom daemon program in C, which is a daemon. The usage is as follows

```
SampleGame /directory1/ /directory2/ /directoryN/
```

I've made the same into a bash script. When I start it, the

```
ps -ely | grep SampleGame
```

reports two instances of the SampleGame.
a screenshot
[image]

When I call this script two instances of SampleGame are made. Don't mind the name. It`s actually a GUI in Qt that shows in one hour to delete specific directories after confirmation. 
[EDIT] I`ve decided to read the input from XML file so, it`s partly solved, it still bugs me why it spawns 2 forks...
[EDIT] Here is the daemon gui in action:
[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the "ps" output that you're referring to, and the relevant parts of this bash script?

Comment: Sorry, don`t know how to format it to code :(

Comment: I`ll add a screenshot.

Comment: Could it be that your bash script is being called twice?

Comment: @AndrewMorton ok how come? I just bash script.sh, why could it be called 2 times?

Comment: @IlianZapryanov I have no idea. But, if it was, then that would be the thing to look for rather than why the program starts twice.

Comment: @AndrewMorton OK, I`ll try to figure it out, but it`s a bit strange, I was expecting the shell script to be a reflection of the shell I am typing in... You can see the latest screenshot. It`s perfectly normal. After 1 hour the GUI is shown, and until you close it or press a button, no other will ever start.. Why such behaviour from .sh I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

We would need far more information to answer the question definitively, but from your screenshot I can see that one of those `SampleGame` processes was launched by the other one, so it seems clear to me that whatever else `SampleGame` is, it appears to exhibit this behavior on its own.

Comment: When I start it from command line it behaves OK. I just wonder why when it`s from script it starts 2 times. SampleGame is obfuscating name, it`s a daemon in C, which calls a Qt GUI in fixed interval, then performs specific operation on the specified directories. Commonly deleting or print contents to file.

Comment: Here is my code https://github.com/heatblazer/DaemonGUI
if you are interested. It`s quite big so just take a look at Daemon.cpp, it may rings a bell. But that behaviour is from script file only. In the terminal it`s OK.